# Best way to make a remote database driven iphone application

Tags: iphone

I have a school project that i think i can do with the concept of secure database driven application , can anybody help me how to do that because i am confused with method will be best and secure. Tutorial link  will be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is relatively simple. You need to send an [HTTP request](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to your server. I like using a [JSON object](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/). Or you can just stick everything into a [POST](http://www.conceitedcode.com/2010/06/sending-post-data-using-nsurlconnection/). If you are just pulling data from a server and not sending any form the iPhone, you can use this [tutorial](http://www.conceitedcode.com/2010/06/using-nsurlconnection/). Your server then can update or select data in a database using your chosen web dev language.

Answer (score 0):

hi friend i think you are talking about to use webservices . in this the data is kept in server and you have to retrive it from server for this you hav to first establish connection using asihttpconnection delegate and parse that data using nsxmlparserdalegate

thanks